# Ubuntu "Failed to restart polkitd.service: Unit polkitd.service not found."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hibernate, policykit

I've been trying to get hibernate working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

It works beautifully using `sudo pm-hibernate` from command-line.

I followed instructions to give me a menu option by creating the file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

This created the menu option, but it was obviously doing something different, because upon re-power-up, the system starts fresh as if from a "hard" shutdown, whilst with `pm-hibernate` the system restores to exactly where I was at.

Through various efforts, I've now lost the menu option, although there remains an option for "Hibernate" under Settings->Power.

I was trying to get the menu option to use `pm-hibernate` instead of `systemctl hibernate`.

I think (but I'm not sure) that the problem came with `sudo apt remove hibernate`

I don't know how to get back the menu option, which appeared after creating the `polkit` file above. That file still exists and is unchanged.

So I tried: `sudo systemctl restart polkitd.service` which responded with:

```
Failed to restart polkitd.service: Unit polkitd.service not found.
```

Even though:

```
sudo apt install policykit-1
```

reports:

```
policykit-1 is already the newest version (0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.1).
```

1. First I want to get `polkit` working again
2. As a separate question I'll then ask how to control which hibernate routine it uses (`pm-hibernate` or `systemctl hibernate`) because one of those works beautifully for me, and the other fails.

Comment: I have identical problem with ubuntu 19.10. Will try to offer bounty for explanation of **not found** message when **newest version** is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's polkit.service, not polkitd.service.

```
[tom@archlinux ~]$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/polkit.service 
[Unit]
Description=Authorization Manager
Documentation=man:polkit(8)

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1
ExecStart=/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
[tom@archlinux ~]$
```

Tip: You could have found out with `dpkg -L policykit-1 | grep service` or even the lists of files of a package on https://packages.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: Much obliged! Answer worth every penny. Will pay after the obligatory 24hrs.